# Verifying OS Name

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just installed ROS Indigo on a new Raspberry Pi model 2. According to the ROS Indigo installation instructions, you must do `lsb_release -a` and ensure that it matches the following:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04"
```

I've installed the Ubuntu 14.04 ARM release, following the instructions linked from the ROS Indigo installation tutorial.

However, the distro identity contained in `/etc/lsb-release` on my Pi 2 does not match the one in the tutorial precisely. Instead, mine says:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

As you can see, there are some minor differences. Will this matter? Should I edit `/etc/lsb-release` so that the file matches the identity text in the Indigo installation tutorial exactly? I was hesitant to do this without being certain, in case changes to the file might interfere with some other part of the OS. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222922/verifying-os-name/) by [tommytwoeyes](https://answers.ros.org/users/1653/tommytwoeyes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2015-12-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do not edit `/etc/lsb-release`. It is an OS file and may be reverted without notice during an upgrade.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tommytwoeyes](https://answers.ros.org/users/1653/tommytwoeyes/) on 2015-12-21**:
Trainman! I have followed your blog for some time now. It's awesome to get a response from you. Thanks!
Ok, I'll leave the file alone. But does that mean those minor differences are unimportant?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-12-21**:
probably... I haven't set up an ARM board in a while, but I get similar results on my x86 desktop. Note that the output of `lsb_release -a` and the contents of `/etc/lsb-release` are related but not the same.

**Comment by [tommytwoeyes](https://answers.ros.org/users/1653/tommytwoeyes/) on 2015-12-21**:
Oh ok, I didn't realize they were different. I'd just assumed calling `lsb_release -a` was equivalent to performing `cat /etc/lsb-release`.